# Image looks blurry in version 12.1

Tags: front-end, version-12.1

**Case 1**

When I use screenshot software screenshot and paste into Mathematica notebook interface, 
the size of the image looks small and hard to adjust.

[image]

**Case 2**

When I rasterize Graphics object into image list, then using ListAnimate or Manipulate to make animation, it looks blurry.

```
list=Table[Rasterize@Plot[Sin[x+a],{x,0,6}],{a,0,2,0.2}];
ListAnimate[list]
```

[image]

I am using Windows 10 1909, I only have one monitor, high dpi zoom is 100%.

Comment: I'm guessing that you have two monitors.  Case #1, is probably because the screen capture tool isn't including the metadata for the physical dimensions of the image.  Since it is not included, we have to assign something...  So it gets assigned to the primary monitor's density.  Assuming that monitor is less dense than the primary, that is why it is smaller.

Comment: For the second case, I assume that it "looks" better with `list = Table[
   Rasterize[Plot[Sin[x + a], {x, 0, 6}], 
    ImageResolution -> CurrentValue["WindowResolution"]], {a, 0, 2, 
    0.2}];
ListAnimate[list]`

Comment: @ihojnicki Thansk, but the effect is not obvious to me.